# Which is the official download for JasperReports Library?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have tried to download JasperReports Library from https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases 
but it is currently not working.

Is this the correct official download link?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library is the official home page of the JasperReports project, and the download links on that page should normally work.  The release files linked from that page are hosted by [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/), maybe there was a temporary service outage at the moment you tried to get the files.

JasperReports release files are also hosted on the [JasperReports GitHub project page](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/releases), and can be downloaded from there if getting them from SourceForge does not work for some reason.

JasperReports release jars are also published on [the central Maven repository](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:net.sf.jasperreports).

Comment: Thanks, maybe also a link to [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports) can be useful